# How does MMC compare to SD in terms of life expectancy?

Tags: sd, nand-flash, mmc

There is supposedly new surface mount SD card ICs on the market (see https://hackaday.com/2020/12/29/new-part-day-sd-nand-are-surface-mount-chips-that-work-like-an-sd-card/) which I thought was interesting. These surface mount SD cards would have two advantages over eMMC for me:

1. They're generally a bit cheaper
2. They're accessible via SPI, which opens up some cool possibilities in the IoT space

Discussions arose regarding the durability of SD cards vs MMC. Anecdotes in the style "SD cards seem to break super fast for me" etc, which I tend to agree with personally. But the question is if this is intrinsic to the technology, or if it's tied to typical usage/packaging.

Further digging gives more claims of eMMC being more robust than SD cards, but I could find nothing that corroborated it with technical arguments or benchmarks. So my question is this:

Is MMC more durable than SD, and if so, for what reason?

Comment: There is no blanket statement which one is more durable. You can get as durable memory as you specify and it comes with a price tag.

Comment: Well it's sort of implied you should do the comparison using comparable price tags. Clearly a $2 SD card will be worse than a $300 MMC.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=SD+vs.+MMC+endurance gives nothing useful.  Until such time as someone qualitatively does an apples-to-apples comparison, this will be unanswerable.  Even then it will likely depend on the exact brands and models tested, and those will change over time.  Get a bunch and wear-test them is all I can suggest (then post the results as the answer here.)

Comment: *Check the datasheet for the parts*!! SD and MMC are just ways of connecting the memory; they don't really have anything to do with how durable the memory is.